# Postgres Recursive get all root parents for selected descendants

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a postgres simple table that has id, and parent_id.
I am struggling on how to query this table, so I can tell it ids of descendants, and it will give me the top most root parents (ones without parent_id).
The thing is that I want to get JUST the parents. They may be multiple parents (because not all descendants belong to the same root parent) AND I want to select just the specific descendants to filter (a subset)